# Barplot subplot legend python

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart, legend, subplot

Hello everyone how can i make legend for 3 different bar color that code with subplot?
Data frame:

[image]

This is my code:

```
fig,axs = plt.subplots(2,3, figsize=(30,20))
axs[0,1].bar(x = df_7_churn_tenure['Kategori'],height = df_7_churn_tenure['Jumlah Churn'],color = ['lightsalmon','maroon','darkorange'])
axs[0,1].legend(['Low Tenure = x<24','Medium Tenure = 24<= x <=48','High Tenure = x >=48'],loc='best',fontsize=12)
plt.show()
```

And the result for barplot legend only shows 1 label like this:

[image]

Is there any solution to shows all of my legend?

Comment: When I tried to test your code, I was missing data (NameError: name 'df_7_kelompok' is not defined).  Please supply the additional code to analyze the issue.

Comment: @NoDakker hello thx for the response. try using code starting from ax[0,1] because that is the main concern. df_7_kelompok is the data frame for pie chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Try this:

fig,axs = plt.subplots(2,3, figsize=(30,20))
axs[0,1].bar(x = df_7_churn_tenure['Kategori'],height = df_7_churn_tenure['Jumlah Churn'],color ['lightsalmon','maroon','darkorange'])

axs = axs[0,1]
lns1 = axs.plot('-',label = 'Low Tenure = x<24')
lns2 = axs.plot('-',label = 'Medium Tenure = 24<= x <=48')
lns3 = axs.plot('-',label = 'High Tenure = x >=48')

# added these three lines
lns = lns1+lns2+lns3
labs = [l.get_label() for l in lns]
axs.legend(lns, labs,loc=0)
plt.show()
```